# How can I test node cron on Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, cron

I'm testing my API with `supertest` package, I do have a business logic that when a property `qrCodeDate` is less than `Date.now()` the `User` status becomes inactive.

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

export default (Model) =>
    new CronJob(
        '0 1 * * *',
        async function () {
            await Model.updateMany(
                { qrCodeDate: { $lt: new Date(Date.now()) } },
                { $set: { status: 'INACTIVE', qrCodeDate: null } }
            );
        },
        null
    );
```

On userModel.ts:

```
// Cron Job to verify if Date.now() > qrCodeDate
const job = CronJob(UserModel);
job.start();
```

And in `users.test.ts` I doing something like this: `expect(User['status']).toBe('INACTIVE');`

On my app, I got those CronJob running everyday checking the condition previously mentioned, anyway, in my test I don't know how to implement, also need the commented line for TS types

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron';
jest.mock('cron');

xtest('Check if when QR Code expires, ordinary status back to INACTIVE', async () => {
        
        // (CronJob as unknown as jest.Mock)

        expect(User['status']).toBe('INACTIVE');
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to test the cron module in your project.
You just need to test the logic inside the function where you are calling `Model.updateMany`.
You can just declare that function separately not in the argument, give it a name and write tests for that function

Comment: Yes, I was getting myself a bit too complex, thought about this later, anyway thank you

Comment: I strongly disagrea with that, what would be the reason for the cron package to always work as expected?